# Delphi 7 Indy 9 multithreaded HTTP Server

Tags: web-services, delphi, webserver, indy, httpserver

I need to write a multithreaded HTTP server. I know Indy handles the threading via IdThreadMgrPool.

My requirements are straightforward: have a server that accepts multiple simultaneous clients (web browser POST requests), runs a limited number of threads that call a Delphi DLL (likely separate to the connection threads), and returns the results.

Non-blocking would be the ultimate (like node.js).

There are several SO posts on this topic. What I can't find here (or via Google) is an example of how to use IdThreadMgrPool. I see posts that say it must be used, but no example how. There is no example on Indy's website either.

Could someone point me to an example? Or is there a FOS framework that will work for this?

One idea is to have Indy spawn multiple threads as normal, then to have these threads access a controlled pool of threads that run the DLL. If this is plausible, then I just need to know the "normal" case usage example.

Comment: Every HTTP request automatically spawns new threads as necessary. I don't believe you would need a thread pool at all, I've never had to use one.

Comment: Then how would I control the number of instances of the DLL that are called? If I have say a dual CPU server, I'd want to have 2 instances of the DLL initialized and waiting for clients. I don't want to spin up the DLL and kill it each time (it's a processing engine and has overheads).

Comment: That makes it very tricky. You shouldn't be doing this per request, because say the server receives 10 requests at the same time. It may need to automatically spawn up to 10 threads to handle all of them concurrently. You don't want to limit Indy to only spawning 2 threads, or it won't work concurrently as intended. You'll need to control this DLL by some other means, before receiving any requests.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what Node.js does. Requests are pooled and served in the background by threads. The request is non-blocking. Impossible with Indy?

Comment: Never say impossible :-) Just very tricky, and that one requirement is even over my head, sorry.

Comment: What if the multiple spawned threads (normal usage) in turn speak to a separate DLL management pool. That should work.

Comment: I'm sure Remy will come along and give you a nice answer, he's far, far more knowledgeable about Indy than me.

Comment: @JerryDodge could you point me to the "normal" way to use this component. I'll try and figure out the rest.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are writing your own server when there are already numerous very good HTTP servers out there that will handle these issues for you? Particularly, if you are on Windows, IIS 7.5 will give you granular control over the things you're asking about, if you write a Delphi ISAPI dll.

Comment: @Vector I don't want to write my own. I'm just stating what I need to do.

Comment: Take the good advice from @Vector.  Let IIS handle the service, and call as many instances of your DLL as needed.  I have one that can handle 40 requests per second, all day long.  I don't worry about threads, Indy, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Windows server available I would suggest writing an ISAPI DLL with Delphi 7 and deploying it on IIS, which will handle all your server side issues, particularly if you have Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 (or better). Your client side can use Indy to connect to IIS, and the Indy client combined with Delphi ISAPI's request/response model support several features which make it easy to pass data from your client into your server side request handler and back to your client. **No  ASP.NET required** - all native Delphi and the "classic" ISAPI application model.

Delphi 7 will generate the ISAPI application code - you get an action editor to handle requests when IIS sends them to your DLL, which is determined by the URL your client sends. You have the ability to persist session information, create global caches and you have essentially all the non-visual aspects of the VCL available within the context of your ISAPI DLL.

IIS handles the threading - will probably handle far more simultaneous connections than you need - and also gives you the ability to determine how many instances of your DLL can be loaded at once, as well as many other options, such as recycling, various forms of authentication and levels of security. You can use the application pooling abilities of IIS for scaling, etc.

I have developed several large scale enterprise level solutions using this architecture (Indy clients embedded in Delphi exe's). It is stable and relatively "painless" once you get down the basics of Delphi's ISAPI application model and the bugaboos of IIS deployment.

If you have this option available, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I have this option available. I'll go with this, thanks.

Comment: @IanC - the trickiest part is deploying properly in IIS. There a lot of settings and options. Most of it is documented in the MS docs online and here on SO, including a few questions I have asked.

Comment: I've set up a VB app on IIS. It wasn't fun. I'll be sure to look through your questions, thanks.

Comment: @IanC -Delphi7 has "WebBroker" (or something like that) framework that you probably want to avoid-it's a funky, proprietary solution, and it's very antiquated. Outside of the ISAPI app framework and the action editor, I have never used it. You can do everything just as in a desktop app and use ISAPI and Indy to send text or data back to your client. You can run database queries on the server with ADO, load your results into a TClientDataSet, send back as XML and load another instance on the client with XML, also grab it, display it and edit it. KBMMemtable also supports streaming binary data.

Answer (score 4):

To use `TIdThreadMgrPool`, at a minimum all you have to do is create an instance of it, assign that to the `TIdHTTPServer.ThreadMgr` property, and set its `PoolSize` property.  All of that can be done at design-time.

Keep in mind that the `PoolSize` does not limit the number of connections on the server.  The server has its own `MaxConnections` property for that purpose.  For example, you could have a `PoolSize` of 10 and have 15 clients connected simultaneously, and thus 15 threads running.  When they disconnect, 10 threads will be put back in the pool and 5 threads will be terminated.

To customize the pool threads, you can derive a new class from `TIdPeerThread`, optionally override its virtual `BeforeExecute()` and `AfterExecute()` methods to perform per-thread initializations the cleanups, and then assign that class to the server's (not the ThreadMgr's)  `ThreadClass` property at runtime before activating the server.  Inside your server event handlers, you can then typecast the provided `TIdPeerThread` object to your custom class and use it as needed.

You can add methods to your custom thread class and have them internally access the DLL, throttling as needed.  The simplest throttle would be to use a single shared semaphore to control the number of threads that can enter the semaphore at a time.  In that regard, you can then limit to, say, 2 threads at a time even if 15 threads are running.

Since you say you want to "run the DLL in a thread", a semaphore will likely not be enough.  In that case, I would recommend using an [I/O Completion Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) instead.  You can have your custom thread class post a request to the IOCP using [`PostQueuedCompletionStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458.aspx) and wait for the response to come back.  Throttling is accomplished by the number of threads you create to service the IOCP, such as one thread per CPU core.  Each IOCP thread would use [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986.aspx) in a loop to receive posted requests.

Indy is not asynchronous, so you would not be able to post a request to the IOCP and let it send a response back to the client directly when ready.  The server sends a response back to the client using the same thread that manages the client connection.  So the client thread will have to post a request to the IOCP and wait for its response, then send that response to the client.  You can define a record that contains a `TEvent`, input values needed for calling the DLL, and output values for the DLL's response.  Then create an instance of that record, post a pointer to it to the IOCP, and wait for the `TEvent` to be signalled. When an IOCP thread receives the record pointer, it can call the DLL as needed, fill the record with the response, and then signal the record's `TEvent`.  The waiting client thread will then be unblocked and can send the record's response data to the client as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Remy. You don't happen to have a link to an example. Always easiest to see working code.

Answer (score 3):

Indy server does not scale well.

Consider using http.sys kernel mode server, iocp based.

Our open source SynCrtSock unit feature a high performance http server, and works perfectly from Delphi 5 up to XE6.

See for instance [this sample code](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/Samples/09%20-%20HttpApi%20web%20server/HttpApiServer.dpr).

Answer (score 1):

See an example here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/xxm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Delphi/http/

The thread pool logic is here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/xxm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Delphi/common/xxmThreadPool.pas

[Xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/) actually provides an interface you can code against so the result is portable over IIS, Apache or the *plain* HTTP server with multi-threading. There's also a http.sys version and a connector to run locally right into Internet Explorer (great for debugging). Each of these also have an 'auto-update' version, that will hot-swap the projects DLL and use it for any new requests (great for live servers).